# Can't get into the Aurora after update. Do I need to start a new save?

Tags: subnautica

The new PRAWN update is out and it recommended that I start a new game, but I'm pretty built up on resources and don't want to do that. So I tried to see if I could work with the already saved one, but it seems there's no way to enter the Aurora now, as the little gap on the side is gone (or hidden below sand but I really doubt that). Also, I can't seem to find an entrance through the broken end where you're supposed to enter in the first place. I even watched videos of people getting in and I don't seem to find the places they do. Do I really have to ditch my saved game?

Comment: The dev notes basically said they changed a lot of the map around, so you definitely need to create a new game. They likely changed the entrance methods for the Aurora, so "new parts of the map will be unavailable in old save games". Sucks, but that's the way it goes with a early access game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to transfer my comment as an answer, since the exact same thing happened in a previous update when I attempted to upgrade an old save game.

Basically the devs have said that the game map has changed considerably in certain areas, and they recommend (as always) starting a new game after a major update. This is the message you get when attempting to load an old game:

[image: subnautica load old save game message]

They highly recommend starting a new game, so troubleshooting an old one is futile. I guarantee if you asked them (or on the forums) for assistance, you will just be told to start a new game. I've gone through this frustration several times over now, but each time it was worth it to see the new content.

In short, yes you have to ditch your old save game.

Comment: thanks.. umm do you know when it will be released exactly? fully? so that we wont have to go through this?

Comment: All depends on the developers. I have no idea, but you can read their dev blog and maybe they will give some insight as to a goal or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever been in before, go to the spot where you remember it being and there is a small crack between sand. You'll need the terra former to get in now.

Comment: The [terraformer](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Removed_Content) is no longer in the game.